# How to get the diff between a tag and its base in Git?

Tags: git, diff, tags, patch

I need to generate a patch of commit with respect to its base. A tag has been marked on that commit. So like on 939023 I do a commit and now it becomes 213232, I will tag 213232 with a label. Now given the label, I need to find out the diff between the 213232 and 939023.

I mean I need a way to generate a diff of any commit whose label is given to its base.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff <commit> <commit>~
```

That will show the difference between a commit and its parent (assuming that you mean the parent when you say “base”).

Shorter version:

```
git show <commit>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git diff 939023..213232
```

Comment: Or just `git diff 939023 213232` (the dots are syntactic sugar)